# How can I adjust the volume of my guitar connected to an iOS device?

Tags: electric-guitar, software

I can't find a good way to play my guitar along with music on my iOS device. The problem with GarageBand is that I can't adjust the guitar and the music separately, because I want loud guitar and quiet music. Also the music gets a nasty echo effect.

There is another app called David Ellefson that allows me to select a song from my playlists to play along with, but music quality is awful and the guitar is too quiet even at 100% volume.

Is there any difference when connecting the guitar via the headphones jack vs. with a USB cable and the cam. connection kit?

Comment: garage band is basically a DAW (Digital audio workstation). This question may be better suited to AV stackexchange, since the "musical practice and performance" is incidental to the question.

Comment: Poll questions are off-topic, I'm going to edit this to ask about your problem directly.

Comment: About recording, not about music performance, so it belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Recording music is on-topic, though horatio is right that you may be better served by [http://avp.stackexchange.com/](http://avp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Plug the guitar into a pre-amp first, then out from the pre-amp to the iOS. A trip to Radio Shack for headphone jacks may be in your future. (1/4" to 1/8" for example)